# mocha --require programmatically

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I use the --require flag to pass Mocha a file with globals set.  I am trying to now use Mocha programmatically following [this example](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically).  I still want the functionality of the globals so I don't have to require everything in each and every test.  Is there a way to do so?  I can't seem to figure out a reasonable way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple load your setup module before you run mocha.

```
require('./setup');
mocha.run(...);
```